# Log round for BCrypt(password, BCrypt(gensalt(80)) IN SPRING BOOT

Tags: spring

I am hashing my passwords in the database with hashing of SHA512. 
and in my spring boot security i am using the below code

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder customPasswordEncoder()
{
     return new PasswordEncoder() {
            @Override
            public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {
                return BCrypt.hashpw(rawPassword.toString(), BCrypt.gensalt(80));
            }
            @Override
            public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
                return BCrypt.checkpw(rawPassword.toString(), encodedPassword);
            }
     };
}
```

But it giving invalid log rounds error. Please suggest me the current number of log rounds for this.

Comment: you are giving it log rounds as 80. which will take huge amount of time to hash the pass. e.g  `A cost factor of 30 could take 44370461014.7 milliseconds to calculate. That is, 739507.68 minutes or 513.55 days!` Try with a smaller log rounds value. Check this link for more details. https://auth0.com/blog/hashing-in-action-understanding-bcrypt/

Answer (score 1):

You are giving it log rounds as 80, which will take huge amount of time to hash the pass. e.g

`A cost factor of 30 could take 44370461014.7 milliseconds to calculate. That is, 739507.68 minutes or 513.55 days!`

Try with a smaller log rounds value. Check this link for more details. regarding the time taken by bcrypt
https://auth0.com/blog/hashing-in-action-understanding-bcrypt/

If you read the spring docs then it is mentioned there.

`The amount of work increases exponentially (2**log_rounds), so each increment is twice as much work. The default log_rounds is 10, and the valid range is 4 to 31.`

Read this for more details https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCrypt.html

Comment: how much should I use for SHA512?

Comment: These two `bcrypt` and `SHA512` are different kind of hashing technique. They are used for different purposes depending upon your requirements. By default the bcrypt has 10 as logrounds. It is good enough for password hashing. you can get the difference between them from here https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/46550/benchmark-differences-between-sha-512-and-bcrypt

Comment: then what should I choose for encrypting my password in the database if I am using bcrypt in spring security.

Comment: You should go with 10 or 11. Just remember the more you increase the number the time required to hash it will increase exponentially making your application slow.

Comment: I tried to make log round 10,11 for the passwords which I am storing with SHA512, but still, it is showing an invalid version. It will be a great help if you help to solve this.

Comment: where are you storing it with SHA-512. From what I can see in your code you are encoding the a simple string with bcrypt.  Just use `return bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(String)`

Comment: In your Spring security config    `@Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }` and then autowire it anywhere you want to use

Comment: still not working, i changed the code but still it is not accepting the hashed passwords.

Comment: share your spring security config and full stacktrace of the error.

Comment: can you share your mail?

Comment: I believe sharing your code here will help you more. As there will be higher chances for it to solve here. If you still don't want to then here is my mail imrawatsvaibhav@gmail.com